# Get data in time range pattern when data and time are in differents arrays

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, linq

I have an array of data (double[] data) and a list of datetimes (List datetimes). Each position of data array is related to the position of the datetimes. I mean: data[i] was collected in datetimes[i].

Now I want to filter the data collected with a week pattern (7 day, 24 hours).
So, I have the week pattern:

```
class WeekPattern
{

    List<DayPattern> week;


    public WeekPattern(List<DayPattern> _week)
    {
        week = _week;
    }

    public bool isInRange(DateTime time)
    {
        return week.Any(i => i.isInRange(time));
    }

}

class DayPattern
{

    DayOfWeek day;
    List<bool> hours;

    public DayPattern(List<bool> _hours, DayOfWeek _day)
    {
        hours = _hours;
        day = _day;
    }

    public bool isInRange(DateTime time)
    {
        if (time.DayOfWeek != day)
            return false;

        return hours[time.Hour];
    }

}
```

Filter the datetimes in range is easy (I have alread Weekpattern pattern object)

```
double[] data = { 1, 2, 3, 4}
string[] times = { "23/01/2013 12:00", "23/01/2013 13:00", "23/01/2013 14:00", "23/01/2013 15:00" }
List<DateTime> datetimes = Array.ConvertAll(_times, time => DateTime.ParseExact(time, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", null)).ToList();

Weekpattern pattern... // Weekpattern object
List<DateTime> filter = datetimes.Where(i => pattern.isInRange(i)).ToList();
```

But, how I get the data filteres (double[] data filtered) instead of datetimes the list of datetimes filtered?

- 1 was collected on 23/01/2013 12:00
- 2 was collected on 23/01/2013 13:00
- 3 was collected on 23/01/2013 14:00
- 4 was collected on 23/01/2013 15:00

Suppose I have a range "Wednesday, 13:00 - 14:00". So I want to get an array of doubles with 2 and 3:

```
data = { 2, 3 }
```

Comment: By "get the data (double[])" do you mean hours/minutes or something?

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. What double[] are you refering to?

Comment: I have 2 lists: a data list (is a double[]), and a time list (is a DateTime List). Each data[i] was collected in time[i]. And I want to get the data that was collected in a range time. So, by the data (double[]) what I mean is the data list filtered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this (this overload of the Select method accepts the element index):

```
        var filteredData = datetimes.Select((date, i) =>
        {
            if (pattern.isInRange(date))
            {
                return data[i];
            }
            else
            {
                return -1;
            }
        });
```

The only problem is that I'll need to verify if the value is equals to -1. But this works for me.

Editing: a better solution would be using the Where method overload that uses the element index on the lambda expression:

```
        var filteredData = data.Where((d, i) =>
        {
            return pattern.isInRange(datetimes[i]);
        });
```

Comment: I think your lambda expression should work great. I can´t check it now, but in a few hours I´ll check it and tick the answer if it works ;)

Comment: double[] result = data.Where((d, i) => pattern.isInRange(datetimes[i]).ToArray(); works perfect. The only "flaw" is when index i in datetimes doesn´t exist. But in my case data array and datetimes array both have the same length :)

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the list of matching dates, simply call the IndexOf() function on the datetimes list for each match then use the return to pull the value out of the double[].

Sample:

```
        var date = new DateTime(2013, 1, 12);
        List<DateTime> dates = new List<DateTime>() { new DateTime(2013, 1, 11), date, new DateTime(2013, 1, 13) };
        double[] values = new double[] { 0, 1, 2 };

        var filtered = dates.Where(x => x == date);
        foreach (var found in filtered)
        {
            Console.Write(values[dates.IndexOf(found)]);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
```